# Dragging multiple polygons on Canvas rerender in React Leaflet

Tags: canvas, leaflet, html5-canvas, geojson, react-leaflet

I am using [React Leaflet](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet) to render Leaflet map and [Leaflet.Path.Drag](https://github.com/w8r/Leaflet.Path.Drag) to drag multiple polygons together. Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-jennings-t25ex).

I have a lot of polygons and would like to drag multiple polygons with [preferCanvas](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#map-prefercanvas) options. If I try to drag multiple polygons with `preferCanvas`, it doesn't work. Dragging makes duplicate polygons on Canvas and polygons are not visible during dragging.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bash-mo7ke)

Answer (score 2):

So I sort of cheated to get this working.  I noticed that when you drag your shapes, the old polygons don't clear, unless you reset the map view by panning or zooming.  So at the end of your drag event, you can just set the view of the map to what it already is, and it will clear the old shapes for you:

```js
layer.on("dragend", function (e) {
  setTransform({ matrix: layer.dragging._matrix, end: true });
  const map = layer._map;
  map.setView(map.getCenter());
});
```

#### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-bush-nutch)

Comment: Thank you! This looks much better, but there is an issue where polygons are not visible during dragging.

Comment: That's true, but as far as I can tell, that issue is present even without my change.  Right now you have `handleFeature` applied to each feature of the GeoJSON, you also need to apply it to the resulting bounds shape that contains the first two shapes.  That's a bit of a different discussion though.  Also FYI, you can replace a lot of your logic wth the L.LatLngBounds [extends](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#latlngbounds-extend) method to get the total bounds of both.

Comment: Thanks for the tip with `LatLngBounds`. What do you mean by `handleFeature` needs to be applied to the resulting bounds shape? It already has `handleFeature` which set `transform` state.